# PSObject is returning system.object and not a string value

Tags: powershell

I am trying to merge data from two different sources and export that into a CSV or txt file by making use of a PSObject.

```
$qry = New-Object System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand("SELECT Name, IsCompliant,LatestEntry,ComputerManufacturerName,ComputerModelName,OperatingSystemName,MachinesUsersNames,ErrorInfoName FROM ComplianceCore.MachinesComplianceView WHERE isCompliant='false'", $conn)
$adapter = New-Object System.Data.SqlClient.SqlDataAdapter $qry
$dataset = New-Object System.Data.DataSet
$adapter.Fill($dataset) | Out-Null

$conn.Close


$resultObject = New-Object -TypeName psobject

foreach ($data in $dataset){
    $resultObject | Add-Member -MemberType NoteProperty -Name Name -Value $dataset.Tables.Name
    $resultObject | Add-Member -MemberType NoteProperty -Name ComputerManufacturer -Value $dataset.Tables.ComputerManufacturerName
    $resultObject | Add-Member -MemberType NoteProperty -Name OperatingSystemName -Value $dataset.Tables.OperatingSystemName
    $resultObject | Add-Member -MemberType NoteProperty -Name Tenant -Value (get-adcomputer -filter * -property CN | Where-Object { $_.Name -in $dataset.tables.name } | select-object CN)
}

$resultObject | Out-file -filePath "C:\BAC\WSUSScripts\MBAM Compliance\MBAMErrors.txt"
```

Also I'd like to run the query against the AD to retrieve some tenant information but no success.

The result is either when i export to csv a system.object or a value something like this {Microsoft Corporation, Dell Inc., Dell Inc., Dell Inc....} when i want everything to be formatted underneath each other in a table.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to create an array and add each data/result object as entry/row to the array.

```
$SQLServer = "SQL_SERVER"
$SQLDatabase = "SQL_DATABASE"
$conn = New-Object System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection("Server=$SQLServer;Database=$SQLDatabase;Integrated Security=True")
$qry = New-Object System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand("SELECT Name, IsCompliant,LatestEntry,ComputerManufacturerName,ComputerModelName,OperatingSystemName,MachinesUsersNames,ErrorInfoName FROM ComplianceCore.MachinesComplianceView WHERE isCompliant='false'", $conn)
$adapter = New-Object System.Data.SqlClient.SqlDataAdapter $qry
$dataset = New-Object System.Data.DataSet
$adapter.Fill($dataset) | Out-Null

$conn.Close
    
$resultArray = foreach ($data in $dataset.Tables[0]){
    $resultObject = New-Object -TypeName psobject
    $resultObject | Add-Member -MemberType NoteProperty -Name Name -Value $data.Name
    $resultObject | Add-Member -MemberType NoteProperty -Name ComputerManufacturer -Value $data.ComputerManufacturerName
    $resultObject | Add-Member -MemberType NoteProperty -Name OperatingSystemName -Value $data.OperatingSystemName
    $resultObject | Add-Member -MemberType NoteProperty -Name Tenant -Value (get-adcomputer -filter * -property CN | Where-Object { $_.Name -in $data.name } | select-object CN)

    $resultObject
}

$resultArray | ConvertTo-CSV -NoTypeInformation | Out-file -filePath "C:\BAC\WSUSScripts\MBAM Compliance\MBAMErrors.txt"
```

Comment: Still returns system.object as the values

Comment: what does `Write-Host $resultArray` give you?

Comment: @{Name=System.Object[]; ComputerManufacturer=System.Object[]; OperatingSystemName=System.Object[]; Tenant=System.Object[]}

Comment: and whats the result of `$dataset.Tables.Name | gm`?

Comment: `$data` instead of `$dataset` within the foreach?

Comment: Ahh, you noticed. :)

Comment: Still returning System.Object[]

Comment: look what `$dataset[0].Tables.Name | gm` returns. piping it to `gm` (which is an alias of `Get-Member` you can see what kind of object/properties you really have.

Comment: I get all different kinds of this info 

TypeName   : System.String
Name       : Clone
MemberType : Method
Definition : System.Object Clone(), System.Object ICloneable.Clone()

Comment: @GuentherSchmitz Is there maybe an easier way to add a tenant column (which i get from the get-adcomputer cmdlet ) to the info that i got from a query that i ran on a database?

Comment: The Get-ADComputer-line can be made more precise (and you'll want to expand the Name-property too) but it isn't the main problem (so far). I have barely even dabbled with [System.DataSet] myself but you might wanna read up on the usage in the documentation.

Comment: so I've updated my answer once again. you have to iterate through `$dataset.Tables[0]` and then have the result rows iterated.